# How do i convert from this org.json into jackson parser?

Tags: android, json, jackson

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("row");

int arrayCount = jsonArray.length();
for(int i=0; i < arrayCount; i++){
      JSONObject jsonData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
      String col0 = jsonData.getString("col0");
      String col1 = jsonData.getString("col1");
      // etc, etc ...
      // put those values in arrays or whatever here.
}
```

What is the syntax for the same operation but using the 'Jackson' parsing libary?

I currently have:

```
JsonFactory f = new MappingJsonFactory();

                        JsonParser jp = f.createParser(res);

                        JsonToken current;
                        current = jp.nextToken();
                        if (current != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                            System.out.println("Error: root should be object: quiting.");
                            return;
                        }
                        while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                            String fieldName = jp.getCurrentName();
                            // move from field name to field value
                            current = jp.nextToken();
                            if (fieldName.equals("row")) {
                                if (current == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {

                                    while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {

                                        JsonNode node = jp.readValueAsTree();
                                        Log.e("KFF", node.get("col0").asText());

                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("KFF", "Error: records should be an array: skipping.");
                                    jp.skipChildren();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.e("KFF", "Unprocessed property: " + fieldName);
                                jp.skipChildren();
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Example of the data i need to parse:

```
http://pastebin.com/rhD2d9fx
```

Comment: What did you try yourself? Essentially you're asking us to write your code for you... have you looked at some of the many examples of using Jackson? For instance: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-streaming-api-to-read-and-write-json/

Comment: It's already there? Underneath the 'I Currently have' sorry if im misunderstanding here.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that it was the Jackson API you were using in the end.
I'll rephrase: what is the problem then? Are you getting an exception or?

Comment: Well currently, it seems as though i've fixed it, or 'bodged' it in such a way it works, simply instead of skipping the children its not an array and literally ignoring the other values it eventually finds the correct tags.